$\mathbb{E}[X^2]\leq k \mathbb{E}[X]^2$, upper bound second moment from first moment
Let $X$ be a non-negative random variable bounded on $[0,1]$. Is it true that $\mathbb{E}[X^2]\leq k \mathbb{E}[X]^2$ for some constant $k$? If not, are there any minimal assumptions on $X$ where this holds?
It's easy to show that this holds for Bernoulli random variables, but I am not sure they are the worst examples.
A related question is Expectation of first of moment of symmetric r.v. in terms of variance, which shows the statement is false for general $X$'s (that are not non-negative).

Also asked at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4898084/mathbbex2-leq-k-mathbbex2-upper-bound-second-moment-from-first-mo where I gave it a similar answer


It's easy to show that this holds for Bernoulli random variables.

By the contrary, the family of Beroulli random variables shows that a fixed finite $k$ cannot exist.  The argument goes the same as the answer you linked.   If $X \sim B(1, p)$, then $E[X] = E[X^2] = p$.  This implies that $
E[X]^2/E[X^2] = p^2/p = p \to 0$
as $p \to 0$, which makes $E[X]^2/E[X^2] \geq k^{-1}$ impossible for any fixed finite $k > 0$.
